# How to add nginx in the following Docker file

Tags: python, docker, nginx

I'm trying to dockerize a python script where it contains a python request for handling the API.
But when I tried to run docker it raises the below error

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='reqres.in', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/users (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9c08686910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution'))
```

For reference code:

```
FROM python:3

ADD ./HMS.py /
ADD ./constants.py /
ADD ./Docker.py /
ADD ./HNT.py /
ADD ./Utility.py /

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org docker
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org grepfunc
RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org requests


CMD [ "python", "./HMS.py" ]
```

May I know what is missing in my code to rectify the aforementioned error.

It tries to build docker image using ->docker build -t ont_alarm_docker .
And inorder to run -> docker run ont_alarm_docker

Hope someone could help as this may be common issue,

## UPDATE

After starting nginix image I was able to get the response. May I know how can I add NGINIX in the above docker file.

Another issue is am not able to write some file when I dockerize the container.May I know the solution for that too

Comment: `... Temporary failure in name resolution')`. The container is unable to access reqres.in. Probably the problem is in docker, not on your container

Comment: @JoaoVitorino when i installed nginix externally I was able to get the response. May I know how can I add that in this DockerFile